# Доступ к элементам коллекции через переменную

Tags: javascript

```
var el = {
    first : {
        earth : '100',
        fire : '200',
        water : '300'
    },
    second : {
        earth : '400',
        fire : '500',
        water : '600'
    }
}

console.log(el.first.fire); //200
```

как реализовать следующий код правильно?

```
var meow = 'water';
console.log(el.first(meow)); //как вставить переменную meow, чтобы получилось 300?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цитата из ресурса: [https://learn.javascript.ru/object#доступ-через-квадратные-скобки](https://learn.javascript.ru/object#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8)

> Существует альтернативный синтаксис работы со свойствами, использующий
>   квадратные скобки объект['свойство']:

Как следствие, ваш код будет таким:

```
var meow = 'water';
console.log(el.first[meow]);
```

Пройдя по ссылке - можно ознакомиться чуть более подробнее